# friendly url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, google-search-console

i have a problem. I made a friendly url rewriting through htaccess, here is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(some-category)$  category/$1/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/(some-category)/$ category/index.php?some-category=$1 [L]
```

And all works fine, but once upon a time i'm look into google webmaster tool and saw a many errors from my urls. Google said that some files don't exist on url => like this `http://domain.com/category//some-category/` what is this? why is this??
i try to open that url in browser and it really exist(some image lost their source, but it work). I don't know why it work, because in my code in htaccess very strong construction with one `/` not two or three, but they work and with 10 `/` in a row. Help me please.

Comment: Are you actually storing `some-category` in $1? or is it just for demonstration here?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes i store some-category to $1, and $1 is a variable that contains "some-category" from left part and paste it to the right part. (it's because "some-category" can be various)

Answer (score 0):

What http header code do those dodgy pages return? You can still have a page that looks ok, but if it returns a 404 code then Google will flag it as missing.

Your images are broken because you must be using relative URLs for them. The doubled slash is adding a subdirectory and messing up that relative path.

I'd suspect you have some messed up links on your website that are going to the dodgy pages. First thing is to find them (the source of your problem) and fix them. Stop the bleeding then clean up the mess.

Comment: i found the solution here it is                                   `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ ((/[^/]+)*)//+([^\ ]*)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .* http://www.yourdomain.com%1/%3 [R=301,L]
`